# python pattern matching joined with a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins

I want to download a build file from jenkins job > last successful build.
The filename is like:
DevPackage-123.pkg where 123 is the last successful build number.
In my python script using urllib, how can I pass this file name as a general variable.
I mean 
filename = "DevPackage-" + <3 digits> + ".pkg"
These 3 digits which represent the build number are unknown to me while running the script.I am looking forwards to adda pattern of 3 digts in the file name.Please help!

```
if jenkins == "branch" and build == "lastsuccessful":
    baselink = "http://" + credentials + "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/job/My_Build_Job/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/results/"
    filelist = ["DevPackage-XXX.pkg","MIBS.zip","udpServer.sh"]

for index in range(len(filelist)):
    urllib.urlretrieve(baselink+filelist[index],newdir+filelist[index])
    print filelist[index]+" Copied!"
```

Comment: filename = "DevPackage-{0}.pkg".format(digits)?

Comment: @Rakesh It didn't work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at first to get the last successful build from Jenkins for given job:

```
import shutils
import os

import requests

res = requests.get("http://{}@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/job/My_Build_Job/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber".format(credentials))
build_number = res.text
```

And after that, you can get last artifacts content:

```
baselink = "http://{}@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/job/My_Build_Job/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/results/{}"
filelist = ["DevPackage-{}.pkg".format(build_number),"MIBS.zip","udpServer.sh"]
for filename in filelist:
    res = requests.get(baselink.format(credentials, filename), stream=True)
    if res.status_code == 200: 

        with open(os.path.join(newdir, filename), "wb") as localfile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(res.raw, localfile)
```